# How can I check the fields I've created?

Tags: 7

I've got a basic question - in Drupal 7 is there a way to simply manage the fields you've created through some sort of UI that is not admin/structure/types/manage/NODE_TYPE/fields?

I'm getting an error:

```
FieldException: Cannot change an existing field's type. in field_update_field() (line 234 of /var/www/vhosts/server_path/modules/field/field.crud.inc).
```

I'm trying to track down why this error is occurring and so far I've had no luck. I've checked some stuff on drupal.org, but I've not been able to find anything definitive to clear this up.

And help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can activate "[Field UI](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/field-ui)" module in your modules list.

Comment: had it enabled, but didn't know where to find it. That's what I was looking for!

For those who may stumble across this in the future, the path is:

admin/reports/fields

Now back to trying to figure what's throwing that error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because you have content with field values of that field. You could create a view that shows you what content is using the field and then go and either delete that content or the field value from the content.

Comment: I've not been able to locate any field that's mentioned in that error, and I've cleaned out a LOT of stuff, but still get the error.